# Disable a hash URL (like http://localhost/#/login) without changing frontend code

Tags: apache, nginx, react-router, frontend, router

I want to disable a hash URL (like http://localhost/#/login)
But I can not change the frontend code.
Can I solve it in some other ways (like Nginx or Apache Config)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec the hash part of the URI is processed on the client-side, and does not get sent to the server. 
So, unfortunately not. 
[reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#media-type-fragid)

Answer (score 0):

1. It can redirect the `#/foo` hash URL in this demo
   https://jsfiddle.net/yaoyuan/exLwhy57/1/
2. Install Nginx.
   Use https://github.com/denji/homebrew-nginx for Mac
3. Install Nginx module for Mac
   https://denji.github.io/homebrew-nginx/#modules
   brew reinstall nginx-full --with-sub-module; Then we can use the sub_filter expression
   https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html
4. delete the js code in demo1.we get demo2 https://jsfiddle.net/yaoyuan/exLwhy57/2/;
5. use this nginx config

```
location / {
     root   html; (use your folder)
     index  index.html index.htm;
     sub_filter </head>
          '</head><script>
           function redirect() {
             if (location.hash === "#/foo") {
                 window.location.replace("https://example.com");
              }
            }
            window.onhashchange = function() {
                if (location.hash === "#/foo") {
                    window.location.replace("https://example.com");
                }
            }
            redirect();
            </script>';
            sub_filter_once on;        
  }
```

6. run `nginx -c nginx.config` to use this config

We can find a new snippet in the HTML, then we solve the question.